# How many Foos, and Boos ? (Linq, GroupBy)

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

**[EDIT1]
I want to have,  "4 Foos, 6 Boos" result using LINQ.
[/EDIT]**

This is elementary one though for me, not so easy.

I have wrote classic code like this. It counts all Foo's an Boo's counts.

```
var myList = new List<string[]>();
myList.Add(new string[] { "Foo", "1" });
myList.Add(new string[] { "Boo", "2" });
myList.Add(new string[] { "Foo", "3" });
myList.Add(new string[] { "Boo", "4" });
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var x in myList)
    if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(x[0]))
        myDictionary[x[0]] += int.Parse(x[1]);
    else
        myDictionary.Add(x[0], int.Parse(x[1]));
MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", 
    myDictionary.Select(x => x.Key +" : "+ x.Value)));
```

**So, I have 4 Foos, 6 Boos.**

I have failed to study, Linq. like this..

```
var myLinq = myList
    .OrderBy(x => x[0])
    .GroupBy(x => x[0])
    .Select(y => new
    {
        Key = y.Key,
        Value = y.Sum(x => x[1])
    });
```

Help please..

Comment: Can you please clarify what is not working in your question please.

Comment: You can't add *strings*. Your *first* snippet parses them to ints. Do the same with the second one

Comment: @BenderBending Actually, all of my LinQ is not proper one. Group "Key" grabs just "2" because it cunts Foo's (or Boo's) existance. I want to summ its counts. Thanks comment

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, so my Non-Linq code used string -> int conversion.

Comment: Take a step back, and explain what output you want for your sample input.

Comment: It's not a conversion, it's *parsing*. You have to *parse* the string if you want to calculate a sum

Comment: @Jason: You say "Group "Key" grabs just "2" because it counts Foo's (or Boo's) existance. I want to summ its counts." - you are using the `Sum` method - if you just parsed your x[1] as an integer it should then sum them. What makes you think it is just counting? And indeed what is returning 2? Your code as it stands I wouldn't expect to work at all due to the fact that as has been said you are trying to add strings...

Comment: 1. Doing an order by before a group by is pointless. Ordering is something you do at the very end.

Comment: @Chrotenise This post is for the purpose of clean question, my real situation is a little bit confused/mixed. If I do not use Ordering gefore Grouping. Grouping gives me some no good (useless) result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the comments, your second snippet is trying to *add* strings as if they were numbers. This produces a compilation error because you have to parse the strings into integers first, before you can add them.

The following code uses `int.Parse` to parse each string to an integer inside the `Sum()` function:

```
var myList = new List<string[]>{
    new string[] { "Foo", "1" },
    new string[] { "Boo", "2" },
    new string[] { "Foo", "3" },
    new string[] { "Boo", "4" },
};

var myLinq = myList
    .OrderBy(x => x[0])
    .GroupBy(x => x[0])
    .Select(y => new
    {
        Key = y.Key,
        Value = y.Sum(x => int.Parse(x[1]))
    });
```

Note, this is a highly unusual way to generate pairs of strings and numbers. It's extremely error prone - what happens if you mix up the indexes? Or a type changes?

It's better to use actual classes, tuples or ValueTuples, for example :

```
var myList = new List<(string,string)>{
    ("Foo", "1" ),
    ("Boo", "2" ),
    ("Foo", "3" ),
    ("Boo", "4" ),
};

var myLinq = myList
    .OrderBy(x => x.Item1)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
    .Select(y => new
    {
        Key = y.Key,
        Value = y.Sum(x => int.Parse(x.Item2))
    });
```

Or

```
var myList = new List<(string key,string value)>{
    ("Foo", "1" ),
    ("Boo", "2" ),
    ("Foo", "3" ),
    ("Boo", "4" ),
};

var myLinq = myList
    .GroupBy(x => x.key)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
    .Select(y => new
    {
        Key = y.Key,
        Value = y.Sum(x => int.Parse(x.value))
    });
```

Notice the change in the order of GroupBy, OrderBy in the last query. Now that I can see what each field does, I can *order* the groups by their *key name* and get:

```
Boo 6 
Foo 4
```

Comment: Note that the `.OrderBy(x => x[0])` is rather pointless.

Comment: @JamesCurran once you give proper names to the fields, you realize the OP wanted to order by the group key

Comment: Perhaps (he's not very clear on the point). But regardless, I don't think the GroupBy would necessarily repect the order of the items, so any OrderBy *before* a GroupBy would be undone.  That was my point.

Comment: @JamesCurran my point is that with indexes, you don't realize that. Once you give names, you can correct the order as the answer shows

Comment: Woo, I was almost there. Thanks nice answer. I've confirmed.

Comment: is it a "tuple" ? Woo I did not noticed that. Good info Thanks..

Comment: order is not important to me (at the moment). thanks

Comment: Why not (string key, int value) ?

Comment: @AndrewP because that what the OP wrote

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sure, but if you are going to move to a slightly more structured approach than a list of string array's, why not take the extra step and also move to a strongly typed structure (which is where the real benefit in your suggestion is)?

Comment: @AndrewP goto -2. I know. That's wasn't the question. Using integers would not answer the *question*. And numeric data *does* come as strings in real life, eg from files or HTTP calls

Answer (score 3):

```
var myLinq = from m in myList
         group m by m[0] into g
         select new
         {
            Key = g.Key,
            Value = g.Sum(gg=>int.Parse(gg[1]))
         };
```

Comment: Can I have "dot style" please ? Thanks comment.

Comment: Can't you just convert that code your own? It is not that hard and you will learn from it. @Jason

Comment: @James Curran Thanks I have confirmed a second ago. And trying to change it into dot style.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yeah. If I can...

Comment: @PatrickHofman Never worry abou it. I have already spent almost 3 hours for just this stuff..

Comment: But would it be fair to someone who is helping you to ask to convert that code while you can do it your own?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have tried to be "very polite". If you saw me not that way, that is all my fault. Thanks for your point.

Comment: Thanks for your understanding. I didn't mean to be rude. It just seems that some users here don't want to do anything themselves. It seems you are not one of them. At least you can respond constructively :) @Jason

Comment: @Jason A tip -- I've been doing this for years, and one thing I've learned is that the lambda syntax ("dot style") is best only if the query is short.  But, if it has a `groupby` or an `orderby` or even a `select`, it's usually better to use the Linq syntax.

Comment: @JamesCurran Hoo.. the last one is another good tip. thanks.. (Mr. Albahari did not give me which is the better one-because he is writing huge huge book). OK I will try use not-dot style from now on.

Answer (score -2):

Why create a Dictionary?

```
var myList = new List<string[]>();
myList.Add(new string[] { "Foo", "1" });
myList.Add(new string[] { "Boo", "2" });
myList.Add(new string[] { "Foo", "3" });
myList.Add(new string[] { "Boo", "4" });

Console.WriteLine("Foo count: " + myList.Where(l => l[0] == "Foo").Count());
Console.WriteLine("Boo count: " + myList.Where(l => l[0] == "Boo").Count());
```

or if you wish to just create a dictionary and use the numbers as a key

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myDict.Add("1", "Foo");
myDict.Add("2", "Boo");
myDict.Add("3", "Foo");
myDict.Add("4", "Boo");

Console.WriteLine("Foo count: " + myDict.Where(l => l.Value == "Foo").Count());
Console.WriteLine("Boo count: " + myDict.Where(l => l.Value == "Boo").Count());
```

Comment: What dictionary? The question is about the LINQ code which has no dictionaries

Comment: @Ben thanks... Your 1st code looks unfamiliar to me. I will study it. (the second one not proper for my situation. the data is given....)

Comment: Naah. the 1st one is not my intention.